# archive.ubuntu.com raring files missing, workaround?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

We have virtual environaments using Virtualbox + Vagrant,

The thing is that the vbox that we where using is no longer supported, so **new** instances of the virtual machine won't work, ( existing ones work great )

This is my vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant/inicio.sh"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/raring/current/raring-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box"

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8107, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 4000, host: 4001, auto_correct: true
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.name = "mallorcagolftours-white"
    end
end
```

This is my inicio.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ ! -f ~/initial_provosioning_done ];
then
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y -q lamp-server^ php5-gd
    sed -i 's,www-data,vagrant,g' /etc/apache2/envvars
    sed -i 's,/var/www,/vagrant/www,g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
    sed -i 's,AllowOverride None,AllowOverride All,g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
    mysqladmin -u root password root
    zcat /vagrant/bd/script.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -proot
    rm -r /var/lock/apache2
    a2enmod rewrite
    service apache2 restart
    touch ~/initial_provosioning_done
fi
```

The problem is that when I run `vagrant up` as usual, I am getting this errors:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please note: I am using vagrant with Virtual box from Mac OS

-EDIT-

I tried with this vbox:

http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box

but then I get this errors:

```
frontend1:mallorcagolftours_white marcos$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu32'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: mallorcagolftoursWhite
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2202.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8108 (adapter 1)
    default: 4000 => 4001 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2202 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2202
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.10
    default: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/marcos/Desktop/Proyectos/mallorcagolftours_white
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/g9/v839m34x1t3fz63r0dqbs27m0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20140805-6746-a3uai1
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
libclass-isa-perl is already the newest version.
libswitch-perl is already the newest version.
libwrap0 is already the newest version.
perl is already the newest version.
perl-modules is already the newest version.
tcpd is already the newest version.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgd2-xpm
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom php-pear libgd-tools
  libipc-sharedcache-perl tinyca mailx openssl-blacklist
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgd2-noxpm
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common
  libaio1 libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libgd2-xpm
  libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18 libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl
  libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 php5-cli php5-common
  php5-gd php5-mysql ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 30 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 119 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libgd2-xpm libaio1 mysql-common libmysqlclient18 libnet-daemon-perl
  libplrpc-perl libdbi-perl libdbd-mysql-perl mysql-client-core-5.5
  libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5
  php5-common php5-cli libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap apache2.2-bin apache2-utils apache2.2-common
  apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5 php5-gd php5-mysql apache2
  libhtml-template-perl mysql-server ssl-cert
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
sed: can't read /etc/apache2/envvars: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /etc/apache2/sites-available/default: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /etc/apache2/sites-available/default: No such file or directory
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 10: mysqladmin: command not found
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 11: mysql: command not found
rm: cannot remove '/var/lock/apache2': No such file or directory
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 13: a2enmod: command not found
apache2: unrecognized service
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: There's no `raring` directories on that server at all: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/, hence your 404 errors.

Comment: Well, this has been working untill (tops) 2 weeks a go, so there must have been changes in the ubuntu servers, recently. the problem I am facing here is that I don't know where to change the url, and what url shall I put?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) reached end of life on 27 January 2014. This means that it not more supported, and one of the effects is that repos don't have anymore the specific packages required to that version.

You should either use a Ubuntu version still active (preferably an LTS version: see [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)) or change your repository list to point to [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/).

In the first case, you need to edit your Vagrantfile, adding the correct box and removing the harcoded url:

```
# Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant/inicio.sh"
# The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
# doesn't already exist on the user's system.
# config.vm.box_url SHOULD BE REMOVED!
```

In the second case, your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should have entries like this:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
# (...)
```

Comment: Hi there, the problem is that I am not even getting in to linux, because it fails; should I use a different `config.vm.box_url` if so, Could you suggest one? The truth is that I wasn't the one that setted the virtual machines using vagrant, very handy; but I really don't know whats going on there.... thanks!

Comment: Ideally you would use a newer version, because you probably will find more problems in the future. You can use `ubuntu/trusty32` instead of `ubuntu32`. If you still want to use that version, the problem happens when you do `apt-get update`. So before that command you can do a `cat` with the required repos.

Comment: Hi, I just tried with the i386 version http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box version, but SAME issue. Any idea?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Please provide the error output. Trusty uses a different set of packages, so you can't get exactly the same error. If you do then Vagarant must be caching something...

Comment: Hi, Updated question with the whole new log, thanks!

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet That's because you are still using the same box. See my edit